# cell decomposition of real homogeneous hypersurfaces

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, gt.geometric-topology, differential-topology, morse-theory, real-algebraic-geometry

Let $f(x_1,\ldots,x_n)\in\mathbf{R}[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ be a homogeneous polynomial 
and consider the real hypersurface $H=\{(x_1,\ldots,x_n)\in\mathbf{R}^n:f(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=1\}$. Assume to simplify that $H$ is smooth.

Q1: Is it possible to compute the number of (topological) connected components
of $H$ in term of the $f$?

Q2: How does one compute a cellular decomposition of a connected component of H ?

Q3: What about Q1 and Q2 in the case where one deals with a quadric of signature $(p,q)$?

Comment: A quadric should be expressible as a homogeneous space of $\text{SO}(p, q)$ (or so) and this should make it straightforward to compute e.g. its de Rham cohomology.

Comment: Re: the number of connected components, here's a family of examples that shows that there is some possibility for interesting behavior here. If $f$ is the polynomial $y \Delta$ where $\Delta$ is the discriminant of a polynomial of degree $n$ as a function of its coefficients, then $H$ is the complement of the discriminant locus and its number of connected components is the number of involutions in $S_n$ (the involution being the action of complex conjugation on the complex roots).

Comment: Hi @Qiaochu; this is an interesting observation.

Comment: Ah, sorry, that should read "number of conjugacy classes of involutions."

Answer (score 1):

There is considerable work on the combinatorics of "arrangements of surfaces," e.g.,

---

[image: DanHalperin]

---

Theorem 21.1.4 there says that for a collection of $n$ algebraic
surfaces in $\mathbb{R}^d$, under various reasonable general-position assumptions,
the combinatorial complexity of the arrangement is $\Theta(n^d)$. So the number of
topological connected components is $\Theta(n^d)$.

For how to computationally construct the arrangement, see

> Efi Fogel, Dan Halperin, Ron Wein.
>   *CGAL Arrangements and Their Applications: A Step-by-Step Guide*.
>   Springer, 2012. ([Springer link](http://www.springer.com/computer/image+processing/book/978-3-642-17282-3))

from which Fig.2.1 below is taken. 

 
 
 
[image: Fig2.1]